# Disruptor helloworld example

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

I want to learn the [Disruptor framework](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/). Who can give me a helloworld example which can run in the main method with Java program language?

Comment: See [The simplest and actual example code of LMAX Disruptor][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168602/the-simplest-and-actual-example-code-of-lmax-disruptor

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a simple, runnable, example of how to use the Disruptor library. Example is written using version 2.10.4 of the Disruptor library.

https://github.com/trevorbernard/disruptor-examples

I've also cross posted on this thread: [The simplest and actual example code of LMAX Disruptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168602/the-simplest-and-actual-example-code-of-lmax-disruptor)

Answer (score 4):

Here One more from my side. I tried one disruptor example using open source Lmax libraries.
I think idea behind the use of lmax disruptor (not the internals of disruptor) is to create message dispatcher and register event listener like consumer.

**You Create a Disruptor, with specifying the message type.**

```
Disruptor<Message> disruptor = new Disruptor<Message>(Message.EVENT_FACTORY, 2048, exec);`
```

**You Create a Handler**

```
 final EventHandler<Message> handler = new EventHandler<Message>() {
        // event will eventually be recycled by the Disruptor after it wraps
        public void onEvent(final Message event, final long sequence, final boolean endOfBatch) throws Exception {
            Integer value = event.getMsg();
            if(value % 10000 == 0){
                System.out.println("ValueEvent: " + value + " Sequence: " + sequence);
                double timeINnanos = (System.nanoTime()-startTime);
                double timetaken = (timeINnanos/1e9);
                System.out.println("Time Taken till now in sec " + timetaken );
            }
        }
    };
```

**Register handler with disruptor**

```
         disruptor.handleEventsWith(handler);
```

**Start that disruptor and pass the returned RingBuffer to your producer**

```
         RingBuffer<Message> ringBuffer = disruptor.start();
         Producer producer = new Producer(ringBuffer);
```

Full code can be found here 
[Github link](https://gist.github.com/rohit-sachan/8413977)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to take a look at the test directory in the LMAX code [LMAX Source Code Test Directory](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/tree/master/src/test/java/com/lmax/disruptor)  . In my opinion its the best source for all kind of things you can do with the LMAX. For the simple example, please take a look at the following link [Simple Example](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/test/java/com/lmax/disruptor/example/ThreeToOneDisruptor.java)

I would also suggest you to take a look at the [DSL examples.](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/tree/master/src/test/java/com/lmax/disruptor/dsl)